# Maven filtering not select the good files

Tags: java, maven

***My project structure:***

```
- src
    - main
    - java
    - resources
    |   -hibernate.cfg.xml
    |   -log4j.properties
    - config
    |   -dev
    |   |   -hibernate.cfg.xml
    |   |   -log4j.properties
```

I use `maven-war-plugin` for filtering with maven.

***pom.xml:***

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <profileVersion>DEV</profileVersion>
            <filterFile>src/main/filters/filter-dev.properties</filterFile>
            <configFolder>src/main/config/dev/</configFolder>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
            <filter>${filterFile}</filter>
        </filters>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${configFolder}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j.properties</include>
                    <include>hibernate.cfg.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>/WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>package-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

***Output console:***

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (package-war) @ with ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [with] in [D:\workspace\with\target\with-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [D:\workspace\with\src/main/config/dev/] to [D:\workspace\with\target\with-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [D:\workspace\with\src/main/config/dev/] to [D:\workspace\with\target\with-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\workspace\with\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [13732 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\workspace\with\target\with-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO]
```

My problem is when i see in the `war` file `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `log4J.properties` are not those of the `dev` profile but those `resources` folder, why ..?

Comment: The maven filtering is intended to inject properties in files, not to select files themselves. So your problem is related with the resources being picked instead. Anyway, why to use filtering and resource selection per profile when you can have just have a resource selection? It makes little sense to me.

Comment: @XtremeBiker because i want to modify some value in files for example increment the version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filtering/Including/Excluding in `maven-war-plugin` is for **web** resources. For main resources use `maven-resources-plugin`. Put something like below into your profile. To include files from your custom directory.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>

   <!-- ... -->

   <build>
     <resources>
       <resource>
         <directory>src/main/config/dev</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
         <includes>
           <include>hibernate.cfg.xml</include>
           <include>log4j.properties</include>
         </includes>
       </resource>
       <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>false</filtering>
         <excludes>
           <exclude>hibernate.cfg.xml</exclude>
           <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
         </excludes>
       </resource>
     </resources>
   </build>

   <!-- ... -->

  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note that here `<filtering>` refers to variable filtering in your resources.

Comment: There is som error with your solution `[ERROR]     Malformed POM ...\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'resources' (position: START_TAG seen ...<
/properties><resources>... @164:28)  @ ....\pom.xml, line 164, column 28` when i put into my profile

Comment: @Mercer `resources` goes into `build`.

Comment: @Mercer BTW in that simple case you can try w/o `excludes`, probably should be working too.

Comment: @Tunaki What for? `<filters>` - *But to organize your project, you may want to put all your variables and their values in a separate file so that you will not have to rewrite your POM, or set their values all the time with every build. This can be done by adding a filter.*

Comment: Because the values the OP wants to filter aren't part of the build. It's not `project.version` but custom properties.

Comment: @Tunaki Strictly speaking OP talks about copying files not filtering.

Comment: @Tunaki I won't change my answer. Instead of removing your answer, you could address that specific issue about filtering in Maven and about `<filters>` configuration.

Comment: @Tunaki You've copy pasted my answer into yours and downvoted my post and now you're playing passive-aggressive on me? Really man you need to cool down.

Comment: @Tunaki *hardcoding path* - It is just an example. Review your original answer and to what you've modified it after seeing my post. As I see it the question is pretty clear. You can take this on meta if you like.

Comment: @Tunaki To clarify things. Tunaki not copy/paste your answer,it helps me from a certain time on my problem. He knows that my questions are not clear because of my English level is low

Comment: @Mercer You don't see it, but they answer significantly changed after I've posted mine. Let's stick to the question, though. Did my answer helped you to solve resource copying problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed 2 things here.

1. you have not made the filtering to true. Because by default
   filtering is false. so you need to make it true under resources

   ```
     <webResources>
       <resource>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
         <!--directory>src/main/webapp</directory-->
         <directory>${configFolder}</directory>
         <includes>
           <include>log4j.properties</include>
           <include>hibernate.cfg.xml</include>
           <!-- include any other file types you want to filter -->
         </includes>
       </resource>
     </webResources>
   ```

   ### Resource Link:

   - [How do I filter resource files to include the values of
     properties?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-resource-files-to-include-the-values-of-properties.html?page=1)
   - [How do I exclude particular resources from being processed?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-exclude-particular-resources-from-being-processed.html;jsessionid=57F5B101AFB473E918E4A31798DF48FB)

Another thing is,

2. By using targetPath, you **override the default destination directory**
   to `/WEB-INF/classes/`. But for fulfilling your purpose to take your
   files in a specific directory, it must not be done. So remove it on
   that case.

remove it `<targetPath>/WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>`

remove this portion from your `pom.xml`

### Related Link:

- [Overriding the default destination directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

I hope it will help you to solve your issue.

For a full example, you can follow the tutorial

- [Using Maven profiles and resource filtering](http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/docs/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering)